# Docker fails to build a Nestjs app with node-crc (rust cargo)

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, rust, nestjs

I have the following `Dockerfile` for my project and I have troubles with building my Nest.js app since one of my dependencies is `"node-crc": "2.0.13"` which somehow fails to build during the `docker build` command.

```
FROM node:17.3.1-alpine

RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y

ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g @nestjs/cli

COPY package.json ./

RUN yarn install

...SOME OTHER CMDs NOT IMPORTANT TO CASE
```

When I use `yarn install` within my project folder, it cause no errors (I use Win11) and node actually works fine, but during the docker image building stage (via WSL 2.0) I got the following error:

```
 > [6/8] RUN yarn install:
#11 102.3 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
#11 102.7 error /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-crc: Command failed.
#11 102.7 Exit code: 1
#11 102.7 Command: npm run build:neon
#11 102.7 Arguments:
#11 102.7 Directory: /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-crc
#11 102.7 Output:
#11 102.7 > node-crc@2.0.13 build:neon
#11 102.7 > cargo-cp-artifact -nc index.node -- cargo build --release --message-format=json-render-diagnostics
#11 102.7
#11 102.7 Error: could not find the `cargo` executable.
#11 102.7
#11 102.7 You can find instructions for installing Rust and Cargo at:
#11 102.7
#11 102.7     https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install
#11 102.7
#11 102.7
#11 102.7 Did not copy "cdylib:node-crc"
#11 102.7 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

So, the question is: *How does this possible?* Espesially after I modify script with  `RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y` which actually should install the necessary rush-cargo build dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was only with the `-alpine` images. It seems it's somehow connected with OS envs.

As for now, I am using images without `alpine` and the build is going fine. I will edit this answer when I find out how to solve a problem for `alpine` images.

Until then, if someone has a better option for `alpine` images, I am ready to accept their answer and mark the question as solved.